# can you identify the error? i am trying to debug the code but i cant see the error

Tags: html, css, frontend

[[image: 1]
can anyone identify the eror]

Comment: add a closing `}` on line 9

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. Also, the error is already **clearly stated in the error message**. Finally, note that images of the code and error messages are not acceptable, your question should **include the code itself** and the error message in text. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is because you have not closed the h1,p selector with closing brace.
It should be as follows:

```
h1,p{
background-color:red;
}
```

/*and then the #top-cloud */